# React.JS: how can I make a form data of an image stored in public folder

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

there's some images in the public folder and when a user chooses one of them, I have to post the image to the server, and **it has to be the image file itself** and not its name or anything else,
the problem is that when I import the image like this:

```
import file1 from "../../../public/static/images/1.png"
```

and then use this code:

```
const data = new FormData();
data.append("useChoice", file1);
```

the result will be empty or not a file. how should I handle it?

Comment: What if you load the image on the server and download it from there? That way, you can pass the absolute path of the image on the server to the server, and it can access it locally rather than receiving an image from the client?

Comment: it's a really good answer and thank you so much for your time, but I've been told to do so, I have no other options but to upload the image itself

Comment: There is a difference between using a file input and simply importing the image. Using the imported image the same way as a file selected by a user doesn't work. There is some workaround however: https://medium.com/trabe/controlled-file-input-components-in-react-3f0d42f901b8

Answer (score 1):

instead of load image and send it to client, then user send it to server again.
u should use link point to those images.
If u must do it that way, try https://webpack.js.org/guides/asset-management/#loading-images

Comment: thank you for answering, I have not tried it in the code yet, but I read the article and I think it must be the answer, so thank you

Comment: @simaghoreyshi If your task is to actually upload the entire file, this is not the correct answer. You'd just send a link to the server, telling the server to download the file themselves.

Comment: @timotgl yes I have to upload the entire file, what should I do? is there a working solution? I've been searching for sooooooo long, It seems such an unprofessional thing to do, but I've been told to do so.

Comment: @simaghoreyshi See my comment to your original question above. I'm sure there is a solution, it's just a bit tricky to use an imported file that way. It's a good exercise btw.